# добавить в список значение элементов этого списка

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс `Item`

```
class Item
{
    public string PropName { get; set; }
    public string PropValue { get; set; }
}
```

Есть список

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item
    {
        PropName = "Property_1", PropValue = "Value_1",
        PropName = "Property_2", PropValue = "Value_2",
        PropName = "Property_3", PropValue = "Value_3",
        PropName = "Property_4", PropValue = "Value_4",
        PropName = "Property_5", PropValue = "Value_5"
    }
}
```

Как можно добавить в список новый элемент, который состоит из определенных значений этого списка? Например:

```
items.Add(new Item {PropName = "Value_1", PropValue = "Value_4"})
items.Add(new Item {PropName = "Value_5", PropValue = "Value_2"})
```

Comment: У списка есть метод для добавления элементов. Используйте его.

Comment: С чем конкретно проблема? Пока ничего не понятно.

Comment: `items.Add(new Item {PropName = items[0].PropValue, PropValue = items[3].PropValue});` - это имеется ввиду?

Comment: Да, затупил чет) Спасибо. Решил так   `var pn1 = items.Find(e => e.PropName.Contains("Property_1")).PropValue;
            var pn2 = items.Find(e => e.PropName.Contains("Property_4")).PropValue;
            items.Add(new Item { PropValue = pn1, PropName = pn2 });`